# Echoing data using foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, foreach

How do I echo the following result data in the view using foreach loop? When I  tried it echoes Null value.

```
 array(13) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#61 (6) {
     ["ad_no"]=> string(5) "11190" ["name"]=> string(15) "Anjitha S Kumar" ["ctype"]=> string(17) "Kerala University" ["cname"]=> string(9) "BSc Maths" ["net_fees"]=> string(7) "6000.00" ["bal_fees"]=> string(4) "0.00" } 
     }

    [1]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> object(stdClass)#60 (6) {
       ["ad_no"]=> string(5) "10879" ["name"]=> string(7) "Adith P" ["ctype"]=> string(5) "C-DIT" ["cname"]=> string(6) "ADCHNE" ["net_fees"]=> string(8) "11500.00" ["bal_fees"]=> string(4) "0.00" } 
    } 

    [2]=> array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#59 (6) { 
      ["ad_no"]=> string(5) "11785" ["name"]=> string(9) "Akshay AS" ["ctype"]=> string(5) "C-DIT" ["cname"]=> string(6) "ADCHNE" ["net_fees"]=> string(8) "11000.00" ["bal_fees"]=> string(7) "9000.00"
     } 
   }
 }
```

Comment: echo var_dump($data_null);

Comment: echo in controller method, populate in view

Comment: Show what code you tried in view

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is named $results you can do (looks you are having array inside array)

View Code:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
   foreach($result as $innerresult) {
   echo $innerresult->ad_no;
   }
}
```

Just make sure you are passing the variable from the controller to your view.

Controller code:

```
$data['results'] = $results;
$this->load->view('viewname',$data);
```

Comment: ;;; Yes, its array inside an array and its was showing null while i send it to the view. Let me try this way as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

From your `var_dump()` result.the data contains array and array contains array of objects.You should try something like this.

```
foreach($data_array as $object_array) {
 foreach($object_array as $object){
    echo $object->ad_no;
    echo $object->name;

  }
}
```